# Get string between “-”

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string: `2015-07-023`. I want to get `07` from this string.

I used RegExp like this

```
var regExp = /\(([^)]+-)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec(id);
console.log(matches);
```

But I get `null` as output.

Any idea is appreciated on how to properly configure the RegExp.

Comment: Have you tried pasting your regex on an online tester like regex101 and look at the explanation?

Comment: i dont know any reex101 tester

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do it is to not use RegEx at all, you can use regular JavaScript string methods:

```
var id_parts = id.split('-');
alert(id_parts[1]);
```

JavaScript string methods is often better than RegEx because it is faster, and it is more straight-forward and readable. Any programmer can read this code and quickly know that is is splitting the string into parts from `id`, and then getting the item at index 1

Answer (score 4):

If you want `regex`, you can use following `regex`. Otherwise, it's better to go with `string` methods as in the answer by @vihan1086.

```js
var str = '2015-07-023';
var matches = str.match(/-(\d+)-/)[1];

document.write(matches);
```

**Regex Explanation**

1. `-`: matches `-` literal
2. `()`: Capturing group
3. `\d+`: Matches one or more digits

**Regex Visualization**

[image: Visualization]

**EDIT**

You can also use `substr` as follow, if the length of the required substring is fixed.

```js
var str = '2015-07-023';

var newStr = str.substr(str.indexOf('-') + 1, 2);

document.write(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below positive lookahead based regex.

```js
var string = "2015-07-02";
alert(string.match(/[^-]+(?=-[^-]*$)/))
```